# Given two cevians in a tetrahedron, how do I know if they intersect?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Given two cevians in the format of barycentric coordinates on the surface triangle of a n-scale tetrahedron.

[image: intersecting cevians]

Next multiplying each cevian's barycentric coordinate by the lcm (value for two cevians' container's scale's) divided by the particular cevian's container's scale.

Now that both cevians are in the same scale how do I know if they intersect?

Comment: Let vertices $P$, $Q$ be connected to opposite points $P'$, $Q'$, and suppose cevians $\overleftrightarrow{PP'}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{QQ'}$ meet at $X$. Then $P$, $Q$, $X$ determines a plane that meets the edge opposite $\overline{PQ}$ at, say, $Y$. Note that this plane contains every point mentioned so far, so it contains both $\overleftrightarrow{PQ'}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{QP'}$,  implying that these lines meet at $Y$. We can conclude that the cevians meet if and only if those other lines meet; you need only convert the "other lines meet" condition into barycentric form.

Comment: I had to re-read this a few times to get it but overall as great math writing as math writing gets. What you said makes perfect sense to me even as someone with low math background. Thank you so much for saving me from going down my own more convoluted route.